# Google BigQuery - ListProjects only returns 1 record

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I want to list all the projects that I have access but it only returns 1 record when I call the ListProjects method from BigQueryClient class.

I verify that I have access for at-least 2 projects by trying to run the code below:

```cs
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create("project1");
var result = client.ExecuteQuery("SELECT col1 FROM `project1.dataset1.table1`", null) //this returns the data from project1
```

```cs
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create("project2");
var result = client.ExecuteQuery("SELECT col1 FROM `project2.dataset2.table2`", null) //this returns the data from project2
```

Both code above returns the data. But when I try to get all the projects using the ListProjects method, it only returns 1 record:

```cs
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(string.Empty);

var projects = client.ListProjects(); //this method only returns 1 record
```

Is there a missing in my code so that I can see all the projects from google BigQuery?

Comment: What Bigquery client library are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2 version 1.42.0.1795 with this project url from nuget: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client

Comment: Could you try with this: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/list to see if the result is expected, if not, fire a bug to BigQuery.

Comment: I wasn't able to use the rest API because I'm using a service account file for authentication. This is exact code that I use https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClient#Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryClient_ListProjects_Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_ListProjectsOptions_

Comment: According to the information given in [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2/), `Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2` library is not recommended for using with bigquery REST API, it mentioned to use [Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/2.0.0-beta04) instead. Have you tried adopting **Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2** to check BigQueryClient `ListProjects` method? Can you reply us with the results?

Comment: BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(string.Empty);  does this return anything or it just return  exception.

Comment: @dee.ronin, can you elaborate more and post the answer if you feel that the issue has been solved, this might further help community members with their research?

Answer (score 1):

The ***string.Empty*** or ***irrelevant*** in `BigQueryClient.Create` doesn't matter. It needs to have a role on the GCP Project that you want to include in the service account.

In my case, I follow the steps below:

1. Go to **Google Cloud Platform -> IAM & Admin -> Manage Resources**
2. Select the project that you want to include
3. Click **Add Member** button
4. Enter the Service Account
5. Select a **Role**. *I choose **BigQuery Metadata Viewer***
6. Click **Save** button.

There is a delayed about 2 minutes before it takes effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(string.Empty);
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create("irrelevant");
PagedEnumerable<ProjectList, CloudProject> projects = client.ListProjects();
foreach (CloudProject project in projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{project.ProjectId}: {project.FriendlyName}");
}
```

try other thing go to your old project and enable  big query.
BigQuery is automatically enabled in new projects.
 To activate BigQuery in a pre-existing project, go to Enable the BigQuery API.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/468bcdc02567a8e337bfa43db3fd523298265225/bigquery/api

I think either you provide right project id or service key.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file

Comment: I already tried that "irrelevant" project name but it still didn't work. I can execute the two queries successfully with different GCP Projects. Is the enabling of BigQuery API per service account or per GCP Project?

Comment: O you have more complexity. I think when you assign credential in client creation . it is per service account. you have to enable it on every gcp  project. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/468bcdc02567a8e337bfa43db3fd523298265225/bigquery/api

Comment: use authentication with key file if you want to use irrelevant word

Comment: Already found the solution, the `string.Empty` or `irrelevant` doesn't matter. It needs to have a role on the GCP Project that you want to include in the service account. In my case, I went to _**Google Cloud Platform -> IAM & Admin -> Manage Resources**_ - > select the project that I want to include -> click **Add Member** button -> Enter my service account -> select a Role **I choose BigQuery Metadata Viewer** ->Click **Save** button. There is a delayed about 2 minutes before it takes effect.

Comment: @dee.ronin great